# .Net WebBrowser control Auto Save document that is downloaded

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am building a tool to auto check mark a few checkboxes on a website, then download the file after clicking the export button. Currently once I "simulate" clicking the export button the SaveFile box pops up and my application loses control and I am unable to save the document. Is there a way to bypass the webBrowser SaveFile box and have it auto save to local disk?

here is current code that gets me to this point.

```
//Login to website
    Dim usernameTextBox As HtmlElement = Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.All.Item("ctl00_UserName")
    usernameTextBox.InnerText = "user"

    Dim passwordTextBox As HtmlElement = Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.All.Item("ctl00_Content_Password")
    passwordTextBox.InnerText = "password"

    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_LoginButton").InvokeMember("click")

    //Wait for page to load otherwise null values for rest of page.
    WaitForPageLoad()
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_LeftNav_LeftNav1_lnkExport").InvokeMember("click")
    WaitForPageLoad()

    //Now Click all Checkboxes
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tvSchooln0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tvStudentn0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tvApplicationn0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tvAppTypen0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tvAppGraden0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tvSept1stn0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tv3rdFridaySeptn0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tv2ndFridayJann0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tvRacen0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tvAddressn0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tvNewAppPriorAttendancen0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tvParent1n0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tvEligibilityn0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_tvParent2n0CheckBox").InvokeMember("click")

    //This is button to download and export to excel
    Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphBody_btnExport").InvokeMember("click")

    //Need something here to auto savee file that is downloaded.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebBrowser control is based on Internet Explorer so I guess you need to change it in the IE preferences to download files directly without asking. That also means that your app behavior will depend on the client IE configuration.
Examples on how you can do this in IE:
https://superuser.com/questions/246553/how-to-disable-file-download-popup-in-internet-explorer